# Matlab - read specifics of textfile and give specific output

Tags: matlab, textscan

I have a text file in Matlab that contains comment strings as well as variables and I am trying to figure out the best way to read this file and give an output as different variables that can easily be plugged into equations later on.

The text file looks something like this:

```
    #Comments
    2
    #Comments
    #Comments
    1.1 2.55 4.32
    1.9 2.76 8.95
    1 3.65 9.12
```

I want an output so that each number is given a variable and the strings with the #s in front are ignored.

ex output:

```
    i=2
    a1=1.1
    b1=2.55
    c1=4.32
    a2=1.9
    b2=2.76
    c2=8.95
    a3=1
    b3=3.65
    c3=9.12
```

And these variables will be stored for later use. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you used `textscan` you can set the `CommentStyle` to `#` - this will ignore the lines starting with a #. Looking at your data, you should set your `delimiter` to a space. As some of your lines seem to be shorter than others you should probably set the `EmptyValue` parameter - this will replace any empty fields with a flag of your choosing, for example `Inf` or `NaN`, or just zero. The command will look something like this:

```
fid = fopen(filename)
data = textscan(fid, '%f%f%f', 'Delimiter', ',', 'CommentStyle', '#', 'EmptyValue', NaN)
```

This will put your data into a cell array - I am not sure how you could elegantly assign each value to a completely different variable.